# How do you replace a pound (currency) sign in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove a pound sign (£) from a string using javascript. I'm trying to do it using

```
str = str.replace(/\£/g, "");
```

However, it is not removing the sign.

The value of str is being fetched from a span (and the correct value is being fetched). This span has been previously set using javascript, with it being encoded in the string as

```
&pound;
```

Any ideas on the best way to remove the pound sign?

Comment: `replace('&pound;', '')`

Comment: @Zirak ... that doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/EUV7c/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may need to use unicode for this.  E.g., `'£10.00'.replace(/\u00A3/g, '');`

Comment: This one seemed to sort it for me quite nicely. Tried some of the other answers, but this one solved the issue. Potentially slightly poor code on my part elsewhere having a knock on effect, so the other solutions may well work for other people.

Comment: I'm guessing that the reason some of the others may not have worked comes down to which charset the page was loaded with (although I haven't verified that). One way or another, there seems to be certain contexts in which the literal '£' character wasn't matching as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the backslash from your regexp.

Comment: A backslash shouldn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 3):

This way it works for me:

```
var str = "£sdfsdf";

str = str.replace("£", "");

alert(str);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/peUrn/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
"hello w£orld".replace(/£/g,"")
```

Comment: it's not necessary when there's only one £ symbol.  Ah... but the author did have it in there... I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is:

```
str.replace('&pound;', '');
```

Comment: This won't work in HTML because a `script` region is "protected". (It's much saner than having to write `if (a &amp;&amp; b) { ... }` like in XML outside of CDATA :-)

Answer (score 1):

Encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, or three escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character

Which means, in order to encode a pound sign, JavaScript uses 2 characters.

```
£ = %C2%A3
```

See http://fyneworks.blogspot.com/2008/06/british-pound-sign-encoding-revisited.html for more information.

It would be best to use %C2%A3 in place of the pound sign in your script.

Comment: This is for encoding into a URL/URI, not about encoding into a string or regex literal (e.g. JavaScript code).

Comment: I know, it is just having the reference may help.